# uniqueness test on minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, minitest

I use minitest on Ruby on Rails. Below is my model.

```
require 'mongoid'
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  index({ pin: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "pin_index" })
  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :pin

  validates :pin,                presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :first_name,         presence: true
  validates :last_name,          presence: true
end
```

I try to write model test.I want to write a test that controls whether pin field is unique or not. How can i do this? Any idea?

I try to write a test like below:

```
it 'must not be valid' do
  person_copy = person.dup
  person.save
  person_copy.save
end
```

Comment: use `person_copy.save!` to raise an error, when uniqueness is false. With RSpec you could use some nice helpers like `expect { person_copy.save! }.to raise_error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the test like this:

```
it 'must have unique pin' do
  person_copy = person.dup
  proc { person_copy.save! }.must_raise(Mongoid::Errors::Validations)
  person_copy.errors.must_include(:pin)
end
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when trying this `NoMethodError: undefined method 'must_raise' for #<Proc:0x00007fdf1eac4518 /Users/xxx/xxx_test.rb:xx>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`assert_includes`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_includes) and [`assert_same`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_same) to test the error is the right one (about uniqueness):

```
it 'must not be valid' do
  person_copy = person.dup
  person.save
  person_copy.save
  assert_includes person.errors, :pin
  assert_same person.errors[:pin], "pin is not unique (replace with actual error message)"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a fixture already set, you can just do this:

```
test 'pin must be unique' do
  new_person = Person.new(@person.attributes)
  refute new_person.valid?
end
```